# i wanto remove listings tags

Tags: wordpress

Here is my footer code from source view:

```
<ul id="menu-footer-menu" class="">
    <li id="menu-item-301" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-301"></li>
    <li id="menu-item-302" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-302"></li>
</ul>
```

i want to remove `<li>` tags
from which file in twentyten theme in wordpress it will be remove?

Comment: you mean widget ????? or just that dot

Comment: people, take it easy on the question marks please!

Comment: only listing tags which is <li id..></li>

Answer (score 1):

make both the ul and li tags display inline

```
#menu-footer-menu ul, #menu-footer-menu li {
    display: inline;
}
```

This should fix the way they're displayed. I would tend towards not using the widgets though, and instead add the code manually to the footer.php file.

Answer (score 0):

using css

```
#menu-footer-menu li {
display:none;
}
```

Comment: i m using fler theme in which no footer class used and here i make dynamiic menu in footer it displays in vertical menu i want it in horizental menu